# In neo4j 3.1, why is the "Total Store Size" larger than the sum of the displayed parts?

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to figure out how neo stores data for data storage space requirements.

When running `:play sysinfo` the following is returned:

`Store Sizes
Array Store         8.00 KiB
Logical Log       236.18 MiB
Node Store          5.18 GiB
Property Store     82.63 GiB
Relationship Store 35.04 GiB
String Store Size  73.68 GiB
Total Store Size  811.29 GiB`

Why is the "Total Store Size" so much larger than the sum of the parts?

Another example from some Neo4j Airplaine/Flight guides:
[image]

Comment: Some of the additional size are for the indexes...

Answer (score 0):

It shows the total size of the directory which also includes

- logfiles
- transaction logs
- indexes

Comment: Yes! I had lots of transaction logs at 250MB each, after clean up we are now at ~333GB (saving of almost half a terabyte)